# Has_many, through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Warning:Total Rails Newb (TRN).  This should be a pretty basic question so I'm hoping someone can spare a couple mins to help shed some light.

Let's say I have the following models: User, Group, and Member
A user can have many groups (let's say friends, family, etc)
A group can have many members, namely other users.

How would I structure this?

Initially I tried this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
end

class Groups < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :members
  belongs_to :user
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

However this gave me an error in User so I changed

```
has_many :groups, :through => :members
```

to

```
has_many :memberships, :through => :members, :source => :groups
```

Still getting an error about missing association when I try to do

```
group = Group.new
group.user.new
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be useful: http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
  has_many :groups_as_owner, :class_name => "Group"
end

class Groups < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :users, :through => :members
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :user_id
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Why when you call `user.groups` does this display the group multiple times in the returned array?  For instance, if you had 2 members in a group and called `user.groups` then that group would show up twice in the array because it is associated with 2 members

Comment: Because it is natural behaviour. It will return not uniq groups, but all associated groupes as much as members have. You can always call `user.groups.uniq` or by `DISTINCT` sql to return uniq groups for user. But actually the problem you are talking about is connected with validation actually. You should validate uniqueness of data you create.

Comment: Well, it's not creating multiple "group #2" in the database, so all group ID's are unique in the db and it shouldn't be a validation thing.  It was just returning the unique group multiple times since it was connected with members.  So you're probably right about just using `user.groups.uniq` to return a unique set.  Thanks for explaining

Comment: It is creating multiple `members` with same references, so it is about validation of `member`

Comment: Great answers!  Here's the issue.  There's still 1 missing link which is that a user is part of groups, but a user ALSO is the owner of groups.  So each group needs to have a user_id field which indicates which user owns it.  While the guides on has_many_through relationships are clear, they don't tell you how to handle multiple relation ships between two models.

Comment: Namely I would need info on how to structure user and groups for this.

Comment: either that or check out the awesome_nested_set gem, its a great addition if you want to track object hierarchies

Comment: Hey great answer floor.  Worked out well.  Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

basically has_many-through associations are n:m associations (join-tables) that (shall) have more attributes than just the id's of the joined record ids...

so you have a table Groups (with an id), a table Users (with an id) and a table Members (no id, but user_id and group_id)

basically, what you did is nearly correct, just think about how you access a group from a user or vice versa....

a user would first look up its member information and through that member information get access to the group information ... and vice versa for a group

so you first set up

```
has_many :members
```

and then call

```
has_many :groups, :through => :members
```

all you need is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
end

class Groups < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :users, :through => :members
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and you have another bug in your code above

you might want to use

```
user = group.users.new
```

instead of

```
user = group.user.new
```

Comment: and again i was a few seconds too slow :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this structure:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
end

class Groups < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :users, :through => :members
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Also take a look at `has_and_belongs_to_many`, if you don't need to do with class Member then you should use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. In this case don't forget to create joining table in the database

Comment: has_and_belongs_to_many is often now replaced by has_many :through because people find (as I've known from real experiences) that very frequently what start out as a simple link table with the two ID's, soon gets changed to reflect additional attributes that become needed, even if just date fields.